# How to add css animation in js for mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, e-commerce

I want to copy some text to clipboard and alert it was copied.

The user clicks/touches the coupon PRIMEIRACOMPRA and it changes "cupom copiado" opacity to 1 and runs an animation to hide it.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCtIZ.png)

***UPDATE:* There was a cache problem and it's working now, but i just realized that the animation does not work a second time, why is that? The function is called on button click so it should run opacity to 1 again, no?**

I have this script:

```
function copyCupom() {
  var copyText = document.querySelector(".offer-right__coupon input");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  var textwascopied = document.querySelector(".offer-right__main .alert-coupon");
  textwascopied.style.opacity = "1";
  textwascopied.style.webkitAnimation = "hideText 1s ease-in 2s";
}
```

this css:

```
.offer-right__main .alert-coupon {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
    transition: 1s all;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hideText {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

The coupon itself is a button calling the function which works fine on desktop, but mobile does not!

```
<button onclick="copyCupom()">
```

What's missing?

The copied text message "Cupom copiado" does not disappear on mobile, i tried adding a webkit animation with no success.

```
textwascopied.style.webkitAnimation = "webkit-hideText 1s ease-in 2s";
textwascopied.style.animation = "hideText 1s ease-in 2s";

@-webkit-keyframes webkit-hideText {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hideText {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try setting the `v-bind:class` attribute to your element by using `v-bind:class="your-class"`, and then modify it with CSS.